# Unable to bind a datatable to a strongly-typed GridView

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, webforms

I'm updating some legacy webform code a little, and am updating an old DataGrid to use a more up-to-date GridView, so that I can then use strongly-typed model binding. A customised DataTable is bound to the GridView programatically:

```
MyCustomCollectionType data = GetFromDataSource();
MyGridView.DataSource = data;
MyGridView.DataBind();
```

and the webform will look something like:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="MyGridView" ItemType="MyCustomCollectionType.MyCustomRow">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#: Item.ID %> : <%#: Item.Name %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

but for some reason, when the DataBind() is called, I get the following exception:

```
[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'MyCustomRow'.]
   ASP.Test_aspx.__DataBind__control54(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Bit\MyRepo\MyProject\Test.aspx:130
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +84
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +150
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +17
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +185
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +17
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +185
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +17
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +185
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +17
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +167
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +3721
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +67
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +128
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +34
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +9
```

If I add a `OnRowDataBound` event handler and check the `RowType`, I can see it databinding the `Header` OK, but as soon as it hits an actual `DataRow`, the exception gets thrown. If I remove the databinding expression altogether, and just put static text in, then the exception disappears and I get the expected number of rows of static text.

So how can I figure out what is going wrong?

**Update**

Interestingly, if I use an `<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" />` and `<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />` instead of the `<asp:TemplateField>` then there is no error. It's only when the databinding expression is called that I get the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding a DataTable to the GridView that is expecting a List to be bound. Either use the GridView as in [this example](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/new-strongly-typed-data-controls-in-asp-net-4-5/), or don't use the `ItemType` property and use `Eval` for databinding.

```
public class SalesPerson
{
    public string SalesPersonID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

List<SalesPerson> salesFolks = new List<SalesPerson>()

GridView1.DataSource = salesFolks;
GridView1.DataBind();

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ItemType="SalesPerson">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Item.FirstName %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**OR**

```
GridView1.DataSource = myDataTable;
GridView1.DataBind();

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#: Eval("FirstName") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When I tried the first GridView example, and tried to bind a `DataTable` to it, I got that error.